# linux fstabs messed up not starting up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fstab

I have modified /etc/fstab and then reboot the Ubuntu machine. I was connecting to this machine via ssh.

it's not promting anymore via ssh for username and password.
how can I via ssh fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome, could you [edit] the question adding more details? For example, what changes did you do to the fstab file? Do you have physical access to the machine?

Comment: In general that's why it is a good idea to make a copy of `/etc/fstab` before changes. Actually I have the paranoid desire to manage `/etc/fstab` with RCS.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, the most likely reason for the system not responding to SSH after editing `/etc/fstab` and rebooting is that you made a mistake and the system is now stuck in emergency mode, waiting for the administrator to login locally on the text console and fix the issue.

If that's what has happened, the boot-up procedure has stopped before it had a chance to configure the network interfaces and start the `sshd` daemon. So the system will not be reachable over the network at all, unless it's a server-grade system with a separate hardware-based management processor with its own networking subsystem.

So the answer is unfortunately "if you need to ask how, then it's probably impossible." You will need to either ask for help from someone who has physical access to the system, or if that is not possible, then you must do the Trip of Shame to visit the system physically and fix it.

A side effect of dependency-based boot process as implemented by `systemd` is that the system will assume all filesystems listed in `/etc/fstab` are critical for the boot process to continue, unless specifically marked as non-critical by using the `nofail` mount option.

If you are configuring a system remotely, and don't have a console access solution in place that is independent of the running OS of the remote system, then it might be a good idea to first make all your `/etc/fstab` additions with the `nofail` mount option added, then reboot and see if it worked.

Comment: +1 for humor; i.e. `Trip of Shame` :) But AFAIK, the `nofail` option in `/etc/fstab` predates `systemd`'s world domination, no?

Comment: @Seamus Perhaps, but not by much I think... and (some) older pre-systemd startup scripts just proceeded onward after spitting error messages to the console, in the hope that whatever was left out was not vital. Not so with `systemd`: if something in `/etc/fstab` cannot be mounted and it's not marked with `nofail`, the system *will* be sitting in emergency mode, guaranteed.

Comment: Actually `nofail` wasn't needed before `systemd`, because then the mount would just fail, while *with* `systemd` the system deliberately goes in to emergency mode.

Comment: @U.Windl: That's very similar to the definition of a *self-inflicted wound*, is it not?